# Elasticsearch: aggregation with interval hour

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aggregate

I have ~100 documents coming in per hour. Every document has a `viewers` property (integer).

By the end of the day I want to aggregate an array of 24 documents, one for every hour of the day, represented by the document with the highest `viewers` count.

My query so far:

```
// query, fetch all documents of a specific day
var query = {
  bool : {
    filter : [
      {
        range : {
          'created' : {
            gte : day,
            lte : day + (60 * 60 * 24)
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

// aggregation
var aggs = {
  // ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be achieved using [Date Histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) plus [Top Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregations. Look at this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "articles_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created",
        "interval": "minute"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Viewers": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "viewers": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Date Histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) aggregation will create buckets for each hour in filtered date range and top hits agg will bring back document with highest viewers (we're ordering documents by viewers in descending order and bringing top 1 hit).

Let me know if this works.